# How to configure none node loggers for rosout

Tags: ros, ros2, logging

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For fine grained configuration of log levels we want to use a none node logger or a child of the node logger. For both I can see the output on the console but not on topic /rosout. Also using --ros-args --enable-rosout-logs did not help.

How can I configure such loggers correctly?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/377016/how-to-configure-none-node-loggers-for-rosout/) by [Sebastian Delling](https://answers.ros.org/users/73224/sebastian-delling/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2021-04-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It appears this is not possible at the moment:
https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/issues/1694

---

Originally posted by [rasmusan-](https://answers.ros.org/users/53040/rasmusan-/) with karma: 51 on 2021-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1